# Restrict Google Map Autocomplete results within specific area data layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a simple form with a starting address and ending address, I have autocomplete on both inputs I would like to restrict the return results only if they match a location within the boundaries added by the geo.json layer on the map data attribute so that a user can not "book" a trip if it's outside of the boundaries. Any help is helpfull, it's a learning project sorry if it's a duplicate I tried the answers provided in the other threads. Thanks ahead any help is helpfull!

[EDIT]

```
    const debug = true;

    if(debug === true){
      console.log('[DEBUG] >', debug);
    } 

    const getQuoteBtn = document.getElementById('get-quote');
    const startAddress = document.getElementById('start_address');
    const dropoffAddress = document.getElementById('dropoff_address');

    const startAddressAutocomplete = new 
    google.maps.places.Autocomplete(startAddress, {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: { 
      country: 'fr',
    }
    });

    const dropoffAddressAutocomplete = new 
    google.maps.places.Autocomplete(dropoffAddress, {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: { 
      country: 'fr',
    }
    });

    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

    getQuoteBtn.addEventListener('click', getQuote);

    function initMap(){
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 8,
       center: {lat: 48.7554899, lng: 2.33333}
    });

    const dataLayer = map.data;
    dataLayer.loadGeoJson('./google.json');
    dataLayer.setStyle({
    fillColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    strokeWeight: 0.2
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map); 
    }

    function getQuote(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(debug === true){
    console.log('[DEBUG] getQuote() startAddress.value, 
     dropoffAddress.value > ', startAddress.value, dropoffAddress.value);
    }   

    if(startAddress.value && dropoffAddress.value != ''){
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, 
       startAddress.value, dropoffAddress.value); 
     } else {
      alert('empty input');
     }
    }   

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, 
    directionsDisplay, start, end) {  

    if(debug === true){
      console.log('[DEBUG] calculateAndDisplayRoute() > ', start, end);
    }   

    directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING', 
        avoidTolls: true, 
        // get distance
        region: 'fr'
      }, function(response, status) {
        // console.log(reponse);
        // recuperer la distance et le temps
        if (status === 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          // get trip duration
          const routeDuration = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
          getTotal(routeDuration, directionsDisplay.getDirections());
          // debug
          if(debug === true){
            console.log('[DEBUG] calculateAndDisplayRoute() const route > 
            ', routeDuration);
          }
        } else {
          alert('Please contact us' + status);
        }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a very long-standing feature request #35822067](https://issuetracker.google.com/35822067) on Google's Public Issue Tracker for this functionality in Autocomplete. You can star it to receive updates and increase the visibility to the engineering team, so hopefully they may implement it one day.

Otherwise, you could try using [`strictBounds: true`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.strictBounds) in the AutocompleteOptions and using a bounding box that is centered over the city to be searched. This may not be guaranteed to work if the bounding box is manually moved by the user, however.